# shell script "Thread: command not found"

Tags: c, linux, shell

So I am trying to write my first shell script that can automatically run some C codes for me. I read some materials online and here is my short shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# script for grading assignment 3

echo -n "Enter the student's index  >"
read index
echo "You entered: $index"

#### Functions

function question_one
{
   gcc -pthread -o $index.1 $index.1.c
   taskset -c 1 ./$index.1 5 5
}

#### Main
$(question_one)
```

As you can see, the shell script is quite simple and what it does is also quite easy to understand. First compile a C source file named like 1.1.c, 2.1.c or 3.1.c and then run the output file with just one single CPU.

When I run this script, looks like it can successfully compile the file but unable to run the output file correctly. The error message is "assignment_three_grading: line 18: Thread: command not found". However, if I type in the commands manually by myself, everything is fine.

Comment: You may find [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) useful. It automatically points out this and other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(question_one)
```

Change this to simply:

```
question_one
```

To invoke a function you just name it as if it were a regular command. Using `$(...)` captures its output and tries to execute that output as another command name: definitely not what you want here.